# Offset + match with a variable vba

Tags: vba, offset, countif

I'm trying to use a variable in an `offset()` and `match()` function. But it doesn't work.

```
For Each Valid_type In Valid_sec_type_range

'test = Valid_sec_type_range.Cells(1, Valid_type_index).Value
'test1 = Chr(34) & Valid_type & Chr(34)

new_range = [OFFSET(Market_value_range,MATCH(Valid_type,sec_type,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(sec_type,Valid_type),1)]
```

and when I use this it works, it seems that the function match and offset do not recognize `Valid_type` as a string.

```
For Each Valid_type In Valid_sec_type_range

'test = Valid_sec_type_range.Cells(1, Valid_type_index).Value
'test1 = Chr(34) & Valid_type & Chr(34)

new_range = [OFFSET(Market_value_range,MATCH("Asset Backed",sec_type,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(sec_type,"Asset Backed"),1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`new_range = [OFFSET(...)]` is a syntactic sugar for this:

```
new_range.Value = Application.Evaluate("[OFFSET(...)]")
```

so yes, your variable name is understood as a literal string, which is then understood as a range name, and you don't have a range of that name.

If you are using VBA, then do it in the VBA way:

```
new_range.Value = Market_value_range.Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Valid_type.Value, sec_type, 0) - 1, 0).Resize(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sec_type, Valid_type.Value), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help !
But It says : Run time error 1004 , Unable to get the Match Property of the worksheetfunction class.

Comment: It means `Valid_type.Value` cannot be found in the `sec_type` range.